# I want to display placeholder date as current date

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, nsdateformatter

I'm using date picker and when I open by default it will be the current date. But now I want to display placeholder date also as current date.

```
private func showDatePicker(_ sender: UITextField){
    datePickerView.datePickerMode = UIDatePicker.Mode.date
    sender.inputView = datePickerView
    let toolbar = UIToolbar();
    toolbar.sizeToFit()
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Done", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(donedatePicker));
    let spaceButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonItem.SystemItem.flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let cancelButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Cancel", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(cancelDatePicker));
    toolbar.setItems([doneButton,spaceButton,cancelButton], animated: false) sender.inputAccessoryView = toolbar sender.inputView = datePickerView;
}

@objc func donedatePicker(){
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    if (selectedDateField == 1){
        datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() as Date
        sOdateTxt.text = formatter.string(from:datePickerView.date)
        sOdateTxt.placeholder=formatter.string(from:datePickerView.date)
    } else if (selectedDateField == 2){
        datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() as Date
        sRdateTxt.text = formatter.string(from:datePickerView.date)
    } else if (selectedDateField == 3){
        datePickerView.minimumDate = NSDate() as Date
        sRecordedTxt.text = formatter.string(from:datePickerView.date)
    }
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
@objc func cancelDatePicker(){
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}
```

placeholder date should be as the current date

Comment: Replace all `NSDate() as Date` with `Date()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set placeholder for the textfields in `viewDidLoad` method with current date using `Date()`

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    formatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yy"
    sOdateTxt.placeholder = formatter.string(from: Date())
    sRdateTxt.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
    sRecordedTxt.text = formatter.string(from: Date())
}
```

You don't need to use `NSDate() as Date` to get current date. You can use `Date()`

Comment: I did but after adding this nothing is visible before placed date also not visible, Can you help me bit more

Comment: Mail id @RajeshKumar R

Answer (score 0):

```
extension Date {
    func toString(format:String) -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        return dateFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
}
```

Usage

`yourtextfield.placeholder = Date().toString(format:"dd-MM-yyyy")`

Comment: hes asking to set placeholder of textfield to currentdate

Comment: @RanjithiOS please upvote the answere if you think its usefull